# np.sum of float64 not equal to corresponding realization in c

Tags: python, numpy, precision

I have written a c extension to do some speedup of np calculation, while an easy calculation shows me a different result, which caused a big difference in the end, an easy demo shows as following.

```c
static PyObject* py_test_arr_sum(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    PyArrayObject *ai1=NULL;
    double res = 0;
    if(!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O", &ai1)) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, REG_BETA"parameters mismatch.");
        return NULL;
    }
    npy_intp *shape = PyArray_SHAPE(ai1);
    double *s = (double *)PyArray_GETPTR1(ai1, 0);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < shape[0]; i++) {
        res += s[i];
    }
    return PyFloat_FromDouble(res);
}
```

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.random(100)
print(x)
print(np.sum(x))
print(mod.test_arr_sum(x))
```

[image]

run the post code above, i got some result above, two result are similar but not the same, i have check numpy's sum realization, but i didn't find out the solution, and i do not know how to explain and fix it.

Comment: That's likely due to floating-point roundoff error.  The Floating Point round off error changes by the order in which the summation is performed, i.e. $((a+b)+c)
+d$ will be different from $(a+b)+(c+d)$. You can use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm in your C code for a more accurate result.

Comment: thks for your reply, I have check numpy issue, it seems that np.sum did not applied with kahan summation(there is a [discussion](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2448)，i readed numpy source code, it shows that it just do the summation by `*(out) = (a) + (b)` and iter it with reduce.

Comment: accutually, numpy applied another summation algorithm. as it talk here [url](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/15122), @piyush_sao，thanks again.